# An online IDE that runs R out of the box

Tags: cloud-service, r

The are plenty of online IDE's e.g. code envy, cloud 9, nitorus, etc, etc but none of them have an R option out of the box. I've tried r-fiddle and it feels like a kind of play thing.

Can somebody direct me to one

Requirements

- Setup and R Project on cloud server without thinking too much about
  infrastructure e.g. one click
- An accessible manageable file system Some way to connect to online
  git / subversion repositories
- Console access for when i need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/). It is a cloud service entirely based on [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) (which in turn **includes** R) and LaTeX.

[image: SMC screenshot]

As you can see, you can mix up various cells with different languages. In the picture I have put a `%latex` cell and a `%R` one. The default of course is Sage, but you can also use `%html` or `%md` for Markdown.

While you are in R mode, the IDE offers you some code snippets:

[image: SMC R options]

Regarding your requirements:

> An accessible manageable file system

The website is based on Linux servers. You can access your home directory and configure it, including changing the `.bashrc` file, installing Python packages and so on.

> Some way to connect to online git / subversion repositories

You can access your projects via SSH with any plan (including the free one) and use `git` locally. You can access arbitrary network locations with the paid version of SageMathCloud.

> Console access for when i need it

Yes, either connect via SSH or create a terminal "file" in your project to access a shell.

[image: SMC Bash]

Answer (score 0):

While it is not online I can strongly recommend [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/).

- Free, Gratis & Open Source + Commercial Licence/Support if required
- Cross Platform
- Desktop or Server editions
- Access RStudio locally
- Syntax highlighting, code completion, and smart indentation
- Execute R code directly from the source editor
- Quickly jump to function definitions
- Easily manage multiple working directories using projects
- Integrated R help and documentation
- Interactive debugger to diagnose and fix errors quickly
- Extensive package development tools
- Can create a new project directly from a new or existing directory, git or subversion.

Below you can see R Studio installing the iR kernel for Jupyter
[image]

I can also recommend trying the [R Kernel](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/) for [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) which lets you embed your R session in a web browser and export to html, pdf, etc., including markdown text, plots, code, etc.